# JavaScript subarray without copying?

Tags: javascript, arrays

All of the documentation for creating sub-arrays I've seen talks about `slice`, which creates a copy of the array. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a slice of an array without copying, so that modifying the slice modifies the original array. For example:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var bar = foo.subarray(2, 4);
console.log(bar); // [2, 3, 4]
bar[0] = 'hello, world';
console.log(bar); // ['hello, world', 3, 4]
console.log(foo); // [1, 'hello, world', 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, @Derek's answer takes `O(n)` to create a subarray of length `n`, whereas we can do it in `O(1)` if we access values with `subarray.get(i)` instead of `subarry[i]`:

```
function make_subarray (array, from, to) {
   return {
      get: function (i) {
          return array[i+from]
      },
      length: to - from
   }
}
```

You would use this like:

```
for (var i=0; i<subarray.length; i++) {
    subarray.get(i)
}
```

Or you can add a `map()` function to the `subarray` definition:

```
function make_subarray (array, from, to) {
   return {
      ...
      map: function (f) {
         for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
            f(this.get(i))
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Each call to `Object.defineProperty(...{get: ...})` in Derek's answer is slow in modern browsers, so it's good to avoid doing a lot of them.

Comment: I believe his intention was to reuse the native syntax while simulating a subarray that references the same piece of memory as in the original array. I agree that it might be asymptotically slower during the creation of the "subarray", but I doubt there will be any noticeable performance difference in practice unless you are handling a huge set of data (in this case choose a better data structure!).

Comment: If the reason for avoiding the copy is that the array is long, doing this in O(1) is the whole point, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure but changing each array access into a function call might have performance issues.

Comment: The O(1) overhead of a function call is much less than the O(n) overhead for large arrays. Function calls are also much cheaper than getters. @CMCDragonkai

Answer (score 6):

This code simulates references (pointers) as in other languages:

```
Array.prototype.subarray = function(i, j){
    var self = this, arr = [];
    for(var n = 0;i <= j; i++, n++){
        (function(i){
            Object.defineProperty(arr, n, {       //Array is an Object
                get: function(){
                    return self[i];
                },
                set: function(value){
                    self[i] = value;
                    return value;
                }
            });   
        })(i);
    }
    return arr;
}


//This is the exact code you have in your question
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var bar = foo.subarray(2, 4);
console.log(bar);                    // [3, 4, 5]
bar[0] = 'hello, world';             // some magic happens here
console.log(bar);                    // ['hello, world', 4, 5]
console.log(foo);                    // [1, 2, 'hello, world', 4, 5]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/y7z9T/

`subarray` does not create a new Array by copying the original Array; it creates a blank Array with custom [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get#Description). One thing to keep mind is that the values in the new array are linked to the index in the original array, instead of its memory location.

```
         index
  0   1    2   3   4
         ┌────────────┐
┌───┬───┬┤───┬───┬───┐│
│ 1 │ 2 ││ 3 │ 4 │ 5 ││
└───┴───┴┤───┴───┴───┘│
         └────────────┘
├──── Whole Array ────┤
         ├─ SubArray ─┤
```

The "sub array" provides a "window" for the original array. You can change and get the containing values in both arrays like you would normally do. Changing either of them will affect both. However, if you try to push new elements into the "sub array" bad things will happen so don't do it.

For more on `defineProperty` please [visit MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: This takes O(n) time, but we can do it in O(1).

Comment: Another variant is by using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) :  const array = [1,2,3,4,5]; const from = 3;  const subarray = new Proxy(array, {get: (array, i) => array[Number(i) + from]}); console.log(subarray[0], subarray[1]);

Answer (score 2):

With the arrival of ES6 `Proxy` it is possible to create a subarray without copying.

```
function subarray(arr, from, to) {
    const sub = new Array(Math.max(0,to-from));
    sub[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        let idx = from;
        return {
            next() { 
                return idx < to 
                     ? { value: arr[idx++], done: false }
                     : { done: true };
            }
        }
    }
    return new Proxy(arr, {
        get(a, key) {
            return key === Symbol.iterator ? sub[Symbol.iterator].bind(sub)
                 : (!isNaN(+key)) ? a[+key+from]
                 : key === 'length' ? sub.length
                 : undefined
        },
        set(a, key, val) { if (!isNaN(+key)) a[+key+from] = val; }
    });
}

//usage ...
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15];
const sub = subarray(array, 2, 5);

for (const i of sub)   // 6, 8, 11
    console.log(i);
sub[1] = 42;
for (let i=0; i<sub.length; i++)  // 6, 42, 11
    console.log(sub[i]);
console.log(sub.length);  // 3
```

Please note:

- `new Array(...)` does not allocate memory (sparse array).
- Setting an element of `sub` also modifies the corresponding element of `array`.
- Applying other native array methods to `sub` should be applied to the original `array` due to the nature of `Proxy`.
- Resetting `sub.length=5` has no effect with that implementation.

Here is a [more indepth discussion](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353886028_Efficient_Handling_of_Polygon_Data_With_The_ES6_Proxy_Object) of the use of `Proxy` with polygon array data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, this is possible, because integer is a simple Datatype, if you rap it in an Object, it would be possible I think.

Here is a working Demo:

```
function co(value)
{
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.data = value;
    obj.setValue = function(value)
    {
        this.data = value;
    }
    return obj;   
}

var foo = [co(1), co(2), co(3), co(4), co(5)];
var bar = foo.slice(2, 4);
console.log(bar);
console.log(foo);
bar[0].setValue('hello, world');
console.log(bar);
console.log(foo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VGLdP/

Comment: Yeah using `slice` doesn't work for what I want. The idea is to get a new view into the *same* array (where the only difference is the starting index), not create a new one.

Comment: It is actually possible, using setters and getters. Not practical, but possible.